# Can I set breakpoints at every return statement in Chrome Devtools in an automated fashion?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints, devtools

I assume this is not possible, but I have some highly complex code which cannot be refactored into smaller component functions due to how rich text editors often work.

The cognitive complexity of this function is very high and it has a dozen or more return statements. It would be wonderful to be able to add breakpoints or logpoints to each without having to do so in the code itself. Is there any approach to doing this?